# How do I set my default printer by network location in Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: networking, windows-10, printer

I use a laptop with Windows 10 Pro. I move between a couple different networks. Each network has their own printers. It would be nice to not have to keep changing the default printer when I move from one network to the other.

At one point, I had this set up on my Windows 7 Pro OS so it would switch the default printer based on which network I was logged into. Been researching this but can't seem to find the same settings in Windows 10 Pro.

One network is Active Directory, while the other is peer to peer. There are no group policies preventing these changes and I have full administrative rights to the laptop, and both networks.

In Windows 10 Pro, how do I set my default printer by network location?

Comment: IIRC, Windows 10 will print to the *last* printer used when connected to a certain network, unless you've disabled this behavior by manually choosing a global default printer.

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for a solution to this as well and I have found what I consider to be an acceptable workaround.

You can use the Task Scheduler to run a batch file that will set your default printer.  You can set the task to run automatically when you connect to a specific wireless network.

I set up two tasks - one for work and one for home.  It successfully changes the default printer automatically with no visible indication (doesn't require user interaction and no windows pop up or anything).

The complete process would be the following:

First, go to Event Viewer in Administrative Tools and under Applications and Services Logs, navigate to Microsoft...Windows...WLAN-AutoConfig...Operational. Look through each entry in the log until you find one that says "WLAN AutoConfig service has successfully connected to a wireless network" then look at the Event ID (probably 8001). On that screen somewhere you should be able to find the SSID of the specific network that log entry refers to. For each network you would like the default printer to change on, find the log entry and do this:

Over on the right under Actions, scroll down and click on 'Attach Task To This Event' - not to be confused with 'Attach a Task To this Log', follow the Task Wizard, name it whatever you want, when you get to Action, select 'Start a Program', point it to your batch file, click Next and on the Finish screen, check the box for 'Open the Properties dialog for this task when I click Finish' On the Properties dialog, under Security Options, select 'Run whether user is logged on or not' and check the box for 'Run with highest privileges' (it will ask for the user account password later). Go to the 'Triggers' tab and select 'Edit', switch the Settings from Basic to Custom and click on 'New Event Filter' then click on the 'XML' tab, check the box for 'Edit query manually' and paste in the following:

```
<QueryList> 
<Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational"> 
<Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig/Operational">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-WLAN-AutoConfig'] and (EventID=8001)]]and *[EventData[Data[@Name='SSID']='YOUR NETWORK NAME']]</Select> 
 </Query> 
</QueryList>
```

Be sure EventID is correct and put in the appropriate SSID with single quotes.  Click on OK and then ensure the box for 'Enabled' is checked and click OK again. Next go to the 'Conditions' tab and make sure the box is unchecked for 'Start the task only if the computer is on AC power' - DO NOT try to use the setting under 'Network' where it says 'Start only if the following network is available' - this will not work. Click OK and you are done for this one.

Repeat the process for each wireless network you want to have a different default printer on - each will need its own batch file and corresponding scheduled task. Hopefully I remembered all the details! Let me know :-)

Comment: Interesting. Can you give more detail on what the batch file does?

Comment: The batch files are simple one line commands:                                                                                         RUNDLL32 PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "Name of Printer"

Comment: Wow! Thanks, but that is a lot of comments. It would be much cleaner if you used the [edit] feature to add this to your answer all in one piece.

Comment: Sorry, I looked for that but managed to miss it right there under my nose...  I did as suggested and edited the answer.